# Error en la Instalacion de Pluggins en Vim

Tags: vim

-A la hora de querer instalar pluggins en  Vim me sale lo siguiente...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Alguna recomendacion?

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué plugin intentas instalar?

Comment: El tema Gruvbox

Comment: Mmm. Veo que es un error común en windows. Intenta ubicar el fichero `.vimrc` y añade el contenido `https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/852#issuecomment-773291996`. Quizá no esté interpretando las rutas bien y de esta manera puedas instalar bien desde powershell. El fichero `.vimrc` en teoría está en tu home. Tu home lo puedes detectar ejecutando desde el propio `vim` lo siguiente: `:echo $HOME`

Comment: @Adrián Si, conozco ese archivo, ese link simplemente lo añado sin mas?

Comment: Abre el enlace, te llevará al último comentario del post. Comenta que insertaron al principio de todo del fichero ese condicional (`if has('win32')...`),

Comment: @Adrián Ya lo hice, sigue sin dejarme...

Comment: Mmm. Leyendo bien lo que me causa curiosidad es el texto del error `git_version_requirement`. ¿Necesitarás git instalado para este plugin?

Comment: @Adrián Ya lo tengo instalado... De hecho al leer ese mensaje lo actualice

Comment: no alcanzo a leer tu error, podrías ponerlo como texto?